# Como checar se um diretório existe no Java?

Tags: java

Estou tentando checar se um diretório digitado num `JTextField` existe ou não. Tentei usar `Files.notExists()` porém o primeiro argumento precisa ser do tipo `Path` e não consegui descobrir como converter de `String`.

```
String caminho = txtDirIndexado.getText().replace("\\", "\\\\");

 if (Files.notExists(caminho, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode criar `Path` a partir de uma `String` é só usar os métodos da classe `Paths` (plural), por exemplo:

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/tmp/foo");
Path p2 = Paths.get(args[0]);
Path p3 = Paths.get(URI.create("file:///Users/joe/FileTest.java"));
```

Só não esqueça que esta nova `API` de arquivos foi adicionada a partir do Java 7.

> Para saber mais Veja a seguinte documentação:
>
> Retirado de http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html
>
> A classe `Path` inclui varios metodos que podem ser usados para obter informações sobre um caminho, acessar elementos de um caminho, converter um caminho em outras formas ou estrair porções de um caminho.
> Existem também métodos para para procurar caminhos e métodos para remover redundâncias.

Answer (score 3):

Um diretório pode ser representado por `java.io.File`, que possui um método `exists()`. Você pode criar um objeto `File`, e chamar o `exists()` da forma:

```
File file = new File(caminho);
if (file.exists()) {
    // fazer algo se diretorio existe
}
```

Voce ainda pode testar se o arquivo se trata realmente de um diretorio usando `isDirectory()`:

```
if (file.exists()) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        String[] conteudo = file.list();
    ...
...
}
```

Veja o javadoc para [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Comment: Estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem no Eclipse: Multiple markers at this line
 - caminho cannot be resolved to a variable
 - The method exists(Path, LinkOption...) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (File, 
  LinkOption)

Comment: @Strokes, `caminho`, na resposta acima é uma variável. Você precisa inicializa-la para usar. Um exemplo: `String caminho = "C:\UmDiretorio";`. Altere o seu código e tente novamente.

Comment: Sim, eu sei disso. Adaptei para o meu código porém continua dando esse erro.
O exemplo do @Leonardo Otto funcionou.